# Android Layout help needed

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I am having difficulty making my layout to work...

What I want to do is have two spinners and a button below those and once the button is clicked, I display the results based on the values selected in the spinners.

```
 -----------
| Spinner 1 |      
 -----------
 -----------
| Spinner 2 |      
 -----------
 -----------
| Button    |      
 -----------

Result 1
Result 2
Result 3
Result 4
Result 5
```

I have tried to put the results in a ListView, but the problem I face is that once the button is clicked, I can see the repetition of Spinner1, Spinner2 and the Button itself multiple times.

The xml for the layout is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />    

    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/done" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/moreContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:orientation="vertical"    
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textColor="#0000ff"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone please advise where am I going wrong?

The code is as follows:

```
package ms.timetable;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
final Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            RetreiveFeedTask rft = new RetreiveFeedTask();
            rft.execute();
        }
    }); 
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    TreeMap<String, String> _timetable = null; 

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        _timetable = FetchTimetableInfo();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String str){
        if (_timetable != null){
            ArrayList<TimeTable> tarr = new ArrayList<TimeTable>();

            Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = _timetable.entrySet().iterator();

            String toastText = "";

            while (it.hasNext())
            {
                Map.Entry<String, String> pairs = (Map.Entry<String, String>)it.next();

                String key = pairs.getKey();
                String value = pairs.getValue();

                toastText = toastText + key + " --- " + value + "\n";
                //System.err.println(key + " --- " + value);
                TimeTable tt = new TimeTable();
                tt.set_line(value);
                String [] tem = key.split("---");

                tt.set_arrival(tem[1]);
                tt.set_departure(tem[1]);

                tarr.add(tt);
            }   

            //Toast.makeText(context, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //tmap.add(_timetable);
            setListAdapter((ListAdapter) new TimetableAdapter(getApplicationContext(), tarr));
        }
    }

    private TreeMap<String, String> FetchTimetableInfo(){
        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        String origin = (String) spinner1.getSelectedItem();
        String destination = (String) spinner2.getSelectedItem();
        //String val = String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem());
        ArrayList<String> linesServOrigin = LineStation.GetServingLines(origin);
        ArrayList<String> linesServDest = LineStation.GetServingLines(destination);

        linesServOrigin.retainAll(linesServDest);

        //ArrayList<String> preferredLines = linesServOrigin.re.retainAll(linesServDest);

        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Selected value is : " + linesServOrigin.get(0));

        try 
        {   
            for (int k = 0; k < linesServOrigin.size(); k++)
            {
                String url = "http://tt.ptv.vic.gov.au/tt/XSLT_REQUEST?itdLPxx_lineMain=" + LineStation.GetLineMain(linesServOrigin.get(0)) + "&itdLPxx_lineID=" + LineStation.GetLineID(linesServOrigin.get(0)) + "&itdLPxx_output=html";

                DataManager dm = new DataManager(url, getApplicationContext());

                ArrayList<String> stationData = dm.GetStationsData();
                ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> timetableData = dm.GetTimetableData();

                ArrayList<String> originTimetable = null;
                ArrayList<String> originTimetable1 = null;
                ArrayList<String> destinationTimetable = null;
                ArrayList<String> destinationTimetable1 = null;

                int origPos = 0;
                int destPos = 0;

                int ctr = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < stationData.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (stationData.get(i).equals(origin) || (origin + " - DEP").equals(stationData.get(i)))
                    {
                        //originTimetable = timetableData[i];
                        origPos = i;
                    }
                    else if (stationData.get(i).equals( destination) || (destination + " - ARR").equals(stationData.get(i)))
                    {
                        //destinationTimetable = timetableData[i];
                        destPos = i;
                    }

                    if (origPos != 0 && destPos != 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (origPos > destPos)
                {
                    dm.SwitchDirection();
                    stationData = dm.GetStationsData();
                    timetableData = dm.GetTimetableData();
                }

                for (int i = stationData.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (stationData.get(i).equals(origin) || (origin + " - DEP").equals(stationData.get(i)))
                    {
                        if (originTimetable == null)
                        {
                            originTimetable = timetableData.get(i);
                        }
                        else if (originTimetable1 == null)
                        {
                            originTimetable1 = timetableData.get(i);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (stationData.get(i).equals(destination) || (destination + " - ARR").equals(stationData.get(i)))
                    {
                        if (destinationTimetable == null)
                        {
                            destinationTimetable = timetableData.get(i);
                        }
                        else if (destinationTimetable1 == null)
                        {
                            destinationTimetable1 = timetableData.get(i);
                        }
                    }
                }

                TreeMap<String, String> ttable = new TreeMap<String, String>();            

                if (originTimetable != null && destinationTimetable != null)
                {
                    //int curtime = Integer.parseInt(DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
                    String temp = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

                    int curtime =Integer.parseInt(temp);
                    System.err.println("Origin timetable size = " + originTimetable.size());
                    System.err.println("Destination timetable size = " + destinationTimetable.size());

                    for (int j = 0; j < originTimetable.size(); j++)
                    {
                        if (Integer.parseInt((originTimetable.get(j))) > curtime)
                        {
                            if (Integer.parseInt((destinationTimetable.get(j))) == -1)
                            {
                                if (destinationTimetable1 == null || (Integer.parseInt(destinationTimetable1.get(j)) == -1))
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }
                            else if (destinationTimetable1 != null && Integer.parseInt(destinationTimetable1.get(j)) == -1)
                            {
                                if (destinationTimetable == null || (Integer.parseInt(destinationTimetable.get(j)) == -1)) 
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }

                            ctr++;

                            if (destinationTimetable1 != null)
                            {
                                if (Integer.parseInt(originTimetable.get(j)) < Integer.parseInt(destinationTimetable1.get(j)))
                                {
                                    ttable.put(originTimetable.get(j) + " --- " + destinationTimetable1.get(j), linesServOrigin.get(k));
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (Integer.parseInt(originTimetable.get(j)) < Integer.parseInt(destinationTimetable.get(j)))
                                {
                                    ttable.put(originTimetable.get(j) + " --- " + destinationTimetable.get(j), linesServOrigin.get(k));
                                }
                            }

                            if (ctr == 5)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    ctr = 0;

                    if (originTimetable1 != null)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < originTimetable1.size(); j++)
                        {
                            if (originTimetable1 != null && Integer.parseInt(originTimetable1.get(j)) > curtime)
                            {

                                if (Integer.parseInt(destinationTimetable.get(j)) == -1)
                                {
                                    if (destinationTimetable1 == null || (Integer.parseInt(destinationTimetable1.get(j)) == -1))
                                    {
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                }
                                else if (destinationTimetable1 != null && Integer.parseInt(destinationTimetable1.get(j)) == -1)
                                {
                                    if (destinationTimetable == null || (Integer.parseInt(destinationTimetable.get(j))) == -1)
                                    {
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                }                                

                                ctr++;

                                if (destinationTimetable1 != null)
                                {
                                    if (Integer.parseInt(originTimetable1.get(j)) < Integer.parseInt(destinationTimetable1.get(j)))
                                    {
                                        ttable.put(originTimetable1.get(j) + " --- " + destinationTimetable1.get(j), linesServOrigin.get(k));
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (Integer.parseInt(originTimetable1.get(j)) < Integer.parseInt(destinationTimetable.get(j)))
                                    {
                                        ttable.put(originTimetable1.get(j) + " --- " + destinationTimetable.get(j), linesServOrigin.get(k));
                                    }
                                }

                                if (ctr == 5)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = ttable.entrySet().iterator();

                    //foreach (KeyValuePair<String, List<String>> item in lineStations)
                    while (it.hasNext())
                    {
                        Map.Entry<String, String> pairs = (Map.Entry<String, String>)it.next();

                        String key = pairs.getKey();
                        String value = pairs.getValue();

                        System.err.println(key + " --- " + value);
                    }   

                    return ttable;
                }
            }


        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

class TimeTable{
    private String _departure, _arrival, _line;

    public TimeTable(){     
    }

    public TimeTable(String departure, String arrival, String line){
        _departure = departure;
        _arrival = arrival;
        _line = line;           
    }

    public String get_departure() {
        return _departure;
    }

    public void set_departure(String _departure) {
        this._departure = _departure;
    }

    public String get_arrival() {
        return _arrival;
    }

    public void set_arrival(String _arrival) {
        this._arrival = _arrival;
    }

    public String get_line() {
        return _line;
    }

    public void set_line(String _line) {
        this._line = _line;
    }
}
}
```

The adapter is as follows:

```
package ms.timetable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import ms.timetable.MainActivity.TimeTable;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TimetableAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TimeTable>{
private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<TimeTable> values; 

public TimetableAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TimeTable> values){
    super(context, R.layout.activity_main, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
} 

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    //System.err.println("Position is : "+position);
    TimeTable tt = values.get(position);
    textView.setText(tt.get_departure());
    textView2.setText(tt.get_arrival());
    return rowView;
}

}
```

Comment: I think we need to see your code, and also I don't understand the role of `textView1` and `textView2`. I think your `LinearLayout` looks OK, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
```

in `getView()` method.

You are inflating whole activity_main in a row and then adding it to a listview.
Put a row for results in separate xml instead of activity_main. So you will have a new xml file say, row.xml which will contain:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textColor="#0000ff"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

So you will have to inflate as

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
```

And then add the generated rows in the listview which is in activity_main.xml.
So your problem will be solved. Hope it helps.